# Combining several probabilities

Tags: probability

This may be slightly basic for this forum but here goes:

I have three probabilities:

1. conversion rate (%) by product
2. conversion rate (%) by salesperson
3. conversion rate (%) by stage

All three probabilities use data from 5 salespeople.

Can I combine the three probabilities to calculate the ultimate likelihood of a sale and if so, what sum should I use? Or if not, how do I need to break the data sets down so that a probability can be calculated for each salesperson's prospects?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to our site!

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't just use (2)?

Answer (score 0):

So I could calculate the probability of conversion based on the product type for each salesperson, giving me (a).

My colleague has told me that if I calculate the probability of a conversion based on the stage, for each salesperson giving me (b) then I can multiply (a) & (b) to calculate the ultimate likelihood of a sale. Thanks anyway.